# initialize object of specified class with data from configuration file

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-configuration

I am using Apache Commons Configuration to read config file in YAML format. Suppose I have a yaml config file with below content

```yaml
user:
  name: dev
  accessLevel: 5
  adminAccess: true
```

And a Java class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer accessLevel;
    private Boolean adminAccess;
}
```

Now I need to initialize an instance of `User` with the values from the config file. As per the Commons Configuration API docs, the below code should have done the job. But the user instance is null.

```java
User user= configuration.get(User.class, "user");
```

Is this use case supported by Commons Configuration?
If yes, what could be wrong in my code/approach?

**Update:**
For hierarchical configurations, a `Node` pointing to a property key has a `value` and list of Child Nodes. After some debugging, it is found that the `get()` call retrieves the Node "user" with the list of child nodes correctly populated but the value field is `null`. It's the "value" of node that gets converted and not the Child Nodes. So, the translation of child nodes to `User.class` would not work. I don't know if there is any customization that can be done to get this working.

Comment: I don’t understand what you said at the end, could you perhaps clarify using an example? What is that you found by debugging, what is null and and what isn’t?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar updated as answer your queries.

Comment: Have you consulted this page from commons-configuration showing how to use the bean property mechanism https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_beans.html#An_Example? Not sure, if the get method by default provides any kind of bean conversion as you are using it.

Comment: @swinkler let me try that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you are not bound to the apache lib, you might consider easy to use sources like shown here with Snake Yaml: https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml or spring properties https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: @swinkler I am using snake-yml. But i wanted to use auto reload mechanism from commons configuration.